# Disabling menu compression in MFC

Tags: mfc

My English is not perfect. I am using Visual C++ 2019 and MFC. At my MDI-program, the menus are compressed: I do not see all the items, there is a double-arrow-like something on bottom of the menu, I always must click to them. I can not disable this. At Resource View, I can not open the whole menu's Properties Page, only for the File, etc. menu's Properties Page. I did not find the disabling on the Properties Page. In the code, in MainFrm.cpp, `CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC` and `CBRS_FLYBY` occur 2+2 times. I tried to put to comment them, but this did not solve the problem. How can I disable the compression? Thank you.

I can not open Properties Page of the whole menu. Maybe it has not Properties Page, or the cause is the lack of High DPI support in Visual Studio. For example, I can not edit icons: the icon editor is unusable. At the generated program, it seems the High DPI support of toolbar is depend on the style. At WinAPI programs, there are 3 pixel stairs: emulates 1/3 resolution. There is 3*96 dpi = 288 dpi at me, 0,16 mm * 3 = 0,48 mm.

Comment: Show the menu definition in the resource script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the application should display all menu items or just the most recently used ones (and the user will have to expand the rest) is an option that can be set by the user: Toolbar Options->Add or Remove Buttons->Customize->Options->Personalized Menus and Toolbars->Menus show recently used commands first. This option is saved in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\ApplicationName\Workspace\MFCToolBarParameters\RecentlyUsedMenus, so the application "remembers" it.

Programmatically it can be changed using the `CMFCMenuBar::SetRecentlyUsedMenus()` function - it's a static function.

It would be best to let the user decide how the application should work, so I would recommend that you do... nothing about it. Or, you could set it to FALSE, but only for the very first time the application is run. Add a new boolean value in the registry, under ...ApplicationName\Workspace or ...ApplicationName\Settings, with a value always set to TRUE. The best place to do this is the `SaveCustomState()` member function of your application class. In the `LoadCustomState()` read that value (default FALSE), and if it is TRUE call `CMFCMenuBar::SetRecentlyUsedMenus(FALSE);`.

Comment: CMFCMenuBar::SetRecentlyUsedMenus() has no effect so. I am writing this program for me. I disabled Toolbar options and Properties. I try to enable newly.

Comment: Thank you. I enabled customization by user, works at now. By the way, my program always starts with a file "Unnamed 1". I used find "OnNewDocument" in current solution / entire project, but I did not find the OnNewDocument call. This is an IDE, I wish to start with open, not creating new files. So, I wish to delete opening new file when my program starts. Is this in registry so?

Comment: `CMFCMenuBar::SetRecentlyUsedMenus()` does have effect, however it takes a boolean parameter with a default value of TRUE, you have to explicitly set it to FALSE if you want to disable it. Or try a different place in your code, although I think `LoadCustomState()` is the most appropriate one.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote to LoadCustomState. Naturally, I tried this with (FALSE), not with (). Not only at now, but before I wrote "no effect".

Comment: Tested it, just to make sure. Indeed, calling `CMFCMenuBar::SetRecentlyUsedMenus(FALSE);` in `LoadCustomState()` will disable the feature and will update the registry entry on exit as well. If you open the Customize dialog the "Menus show recently used commands first" option will be unchecked, even if a value of TRUE was read from the registry, because the subsequent `CMFCMenuBar::SetRecentlyUsedMenus(FALSE);` call sets it to FALSE anyhow. What to you mean it has no effect?

Comment: "What to you mean it has no effect?" I wrote to OnCreate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CMFCMenuBar::SetShowAllCommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubar-class?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019#setshowallcommands)

> Remarks
>
> If a menu does not display all the menu commands, it hides the commands that are rarely used.

Comment: It has no effect. I wrote directly before return 0; in CMainFrame::OnCreate.